# Undefined httpcontext on inheritance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, inheritance, webforms, httpcontext

I have a Page that is inheriting from a base class

```
Partial Class MyPage
Inherits BasePage

End Class
```

The base class is:

```
Partial Public Class BasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Overloads Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    ' some code here
End Sub
End Class
```

From my page I am trying to access HttpContext.Current but this is always undefined. I am getting an Object not set to an instance of an object when trying to access it.

If I set my page to inherit directly from Page instead of my base class (as normal) then it works as expected.

Why can I not access HttpContext.Current when my page inherits from my base class ? I would have thought that my base class would inherit all properties and methods of the parent page class ?

Any help greatly appreciated,